# multi php.ini files in my system

Tags: user-agent, php

I have Linux Ubuntu 10.10 and when i run the below in a terminal:

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

I got the loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

While if I use `phpinfo()` in the browser it will be:

> Loaded Configuration File /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Which means that there are different ini files according to php_sapi_name!!

now the question is how can i set the same php.ini for all user agents (browser, cli, etc) without copying the same file to different locations!?

Comment: Leave the individual SAPI configurations alone (due to the diverse runtimes they should not be compound for security and efficiency reasons). If you want to set overrides, create a custom script as `/etc/php5/conf.d/your.ini`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sometimes you can have more than one php.ini to manage different interfaces or websites
for example you can have different php.ini for each website you host on your server by setting PHPINIDir in your virtualhost as below

```
<VirtualHost 10.24.11.2:80>
ServerName foo.com
ServerAlias www.foo.com
PHPINIDir /var/www/html/foo
</VirtualHost>
```

however, if you like to make only one php.ini for all interfaces, the only way is to use symlinks as below:
ln -s /etc/php5/cli/php.ini  /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Answer (score 2):

I don't think setting all the different php contexts to use the same config is a good idea in the first place but if you really want to, you could just have one php.ini and all the others be symbolic links.

I don't think there is a way to change php's behavior as to which file it will include without at the very least recompiling it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use symlinks.

```
ln -s /etc/php5/cli/php.ini  /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

Answer (score 1):

What about replacing one of them with a symlink?

Answer (score 1):

You can use symlinks (Apache is using this technique for sites-available and sites-enabled).
So navigate to

```
cd /etc/php5/
```

and copy your desired php.ini file there, then navigate to cli/ and apache2/ - remove php.ini (mv or rm it) and then run

```
cd /etc/php5/apache2
mv php.ini php.ini.bkp
ln -s php.ini ../php.ini
```

This will create a symlink to php.ini in your /etc/php5/apache2/ and /etc/php5/cli/ folders.

Note: It is a good practice to have diff. php.ini files, for cli there are few extensions that are not loadable and much more. :)

Comment: Oh, I still don't pay attention on this little orange header telling me stuff, while I am writing down my answer.